# Php looping an array for hiding option in a `select`

Tags: php, arrays

I having trouble with my array for my **`select`**. The **`option`** value is base from **`$a`**. What do i need to **add in my code** so that if **`$a`** has an equal value from **`$b`**, option will be **`hidden`**.

My array

```
$a = array("1","2","3","4","5","6");
$b = array("2","4","6");
```

Php

```
<select>
  <?php foreach ($a as $i) {?>
    <option> value="<?php echo $i; ?>" >
      <?php echo i?>
    </option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
 <select>
          <?php foreach ($a as $i) {
        if(!in_array($i, $b)) {  

        ?>
            <option> value="<?php echo $i; ?>" >
              <?php echo i?>
            </option>
          <?php }} ?>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this**

```
    <?php 
       $a = array("1","2","3","4","5","6");
       $b = array("2","4","6"); ?>


         <select>
            <?php foreach ($a as $i) {

              if (!in_array($i,$b)) {?> 
                <option  value="<?php echo $i; ?>" >
                <?php echo $i?>
                 </option>

           <?php }} ?>
         </select>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_in_array.asp

Answer (score 1):

you just need to check if the values is not in $b array this way

```
$a = array("1","2","3","4","5","6");
$b = array("2","4","6");
```

Php

```
<select>
    <?php foreach ($a as $i) {
      if(!in_array($i,$b)){
      ?>
        <option> value="<?php echo $i; ?>" >
          <?php echo i?>
        </option>
      <?php } 
      } ?>    
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check array value exist by `in_array` and add hidden attribute to your elements if exist in array `b`

```
<select>
  <?php 
  foreach ($a as $i) {
      if(in_array($i,$b)){
            echo '<option value="$i" hidden>';
        }
        else{
            echo '<option value="$i">';
       }
     echo $i.' </option>';
    }
   ?>
</select>
```